# Wordpress REST API Media Upload: "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content\/uploads\/"

Tags: python, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am honestly kind of lost at this point, I am trying to upload an image to WordPress in Python using this:

```
media_endpoint = 'https://wpurl/wp-json/wp/v2/media?custom_dir=news'

            headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
                'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename={image_name}'
            }

            response = requests.post(
                media_endpoint,
                headers=headers,
                data=image_data,
                auth=auth
            )
```

I am repeatedly getting this error

> {"code":"rest_upload_sideload_error","message":"The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2023/10.","data":{"status":500}}

I saw some solving the issue creating a new folder/letting the folder be created in the API call, but still I get this error:

> {"code":"rest_upload_sideload_error","message":"The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/news.","data":{"status":500}}

(Folder does indeed exist on the server at the given path with the filter function working as intended it seems

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'custom_upload_dir');
function custom_upload_dir($directory) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['custom_dir']) && !empty($_REQUEST['custom_dir'])) {
        $custom_dir = '/' . sanitize_file_name($_REQUEST['custom_dir']);
        $directory['path'] = str_replace($directory['subdir'], $custom_dir, $directory['path']);
        $directory['url'] = str_replace($directory['subdir'], $custom_dir, $directory['url']);
        $directory['subdir'] = $custom_dir;
    }
    return $directory;
}
```

Now I checked the file permissions, and set them using

```
sudo chown -R ploi:ploi uploads
```

I have checked and all folders have these as permissions, also set to 755 and so on, also tried `sudo usermod -a -G www-data ploi` and `sudo chown -R ploi:www-data uploads` also still same error

There also are no logs pertaining to this in my wp debug.log or the nginx error.log

Is there anything I'm missing? Uploading posts via API works without issue, it's just when it comes to media uploads I cant seem to get it working

Uploading media via WordPress Rest API results in can't move uploaded file to /uploads error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used Wordpress in a Docker container and I solved a the same error message of not being able to upload an image as following:

```bash
docker compose exec -u 0 wordpress bash
# In your wordpress shell
cd wp-content/
ls -lah
chown www-data:www-data ./* -R
ls -lah
```

**Explanation**

1. Go into a bash terminal of your docker container (mine called `wordpress`) as root user with `-u 0`
2. `cd` into the wordpress content folder, where the uploaded data is stored
3. Check your permissions with `ls -lah` -> if www-data is not shown here, you should be on the right way
   Here, my output was:

```bash
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 28 13:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 27 16:28 ..
drwxrwxrwt 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb  1 03:57 cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 28 13:39 plugins
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4.0K Jan 30 19:27 themes
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4.0K Feb 28 13:39 upgrade
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4.0K Feb 28 13:39 uploads
```

4. Recursively change user and group ownership to `www-data`
5. Check your permissions again to see any changes. My output changed to

```bash
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 28 13:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 27 16:28 ..
drwxrwxrwt 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb  1 03:57 cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 28 13:39 plugins
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4.0K Jan 30 19:27 themes
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 28 13:39 upgrade
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 28 13:39 uploads
```

and afterwards I was able to uplaod my images.